# network link speed is changing on it's own

Tags: networking, windows-7, network-speed

We have a server; win7 64bit with 2 network adapters: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller.

We have a software running on that machine which is recording 40Mbit/sec of streaming data (UDP + RTP ) into the disk. Link speed is 1 Gbps. When we leave that machine for one night, next morning we saw that the LAN connection was dropped to 100 Mbps with a 99% of usage. I am not sure what caused that drop but disabling/enabling the network adapter is solving it ( temproraly ). Is there some sort of system log that I can track the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the cable. Most likely it's broken and causing instability which then makes link renegotiate on slower speed.